# What equipment does an A320 need in order to operate under RNP 2?

Tags: navigation, aircraft-systems, airbus-a320

What are the aircraft equipment/systems eligibility requirements for Airbus A320 airplanes to operate in RNP 2 airspace?

Comment: In which country? See page 32-33 of this [ICAO presentation](http://www2010.icao.int/NACC/documents/meetings/2013/pbn2013/ops7-en.pdf). For India, [this operating circular](http://dgca.nic.in/circular/ops14_2014.pdf) is relevant, for Autralia this is [this one](https://www.legislation.gov.au/Details/F2014L01703). RNP is not an airspace, but a navigation mode like RNAV. All RNP modes and RNAV are part of [PBN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Performance-based_navigation).

Comment: Are dual navigation autopilot and GNSS systems required for RNP2 despatch purposes?

Comment: @user175574  No, a single autopilot would be fine, and in fact I suspect that no autopilot wouldn't disqualify for RNP 2, at least in the US.  Also, GNSS wouldn't be required in MOST airspace, because DME/DME updates are plenty accurate for RNP 2, if/where there are enough Navaids close by.  Over the ocean, then yes you'd need GNSS.  RNP 2 isn't very demanding -- essentially any A320 has more than enough to meet the requirements for it.

Comment: At least one engine :)

Answer (score 6):

According to ICAO/EASA till 12/2015 Version.
And from **Airbus getting to grips with modern navigation**.

> Regulatory Authorities have published standards for specific
>   airspaces. Provide certification and operational requirements for
>   Basic RNAV (RNP-5 Type) and for Precision RNAV (RNP1 Type) within
>   European airspace (refer to Annexes 5.1 and 5.2 at the end). FAA Order
>   8400.12A addresses RNP-10 operations in oceanic and remote areas (refer to Annex 5.3 at the end). Also RNP AR required equipment is
>   specified in several sources and the FCOM manual of airbus. In
>   addition for **RNP 2 specific terminal and approach operations** the
>   requirements are specified on the approach charts of airports that implementing it.

Most of the operators/airlines are using the standard required equipment for **RNP 1**.

> **According to FCOM A319/A320/A321 FLEET** / **PRO-SPO-51 P 8/10** The minimum navigation equipment required to enter **RNP 1** airspace is:
>
> **‐ One FMGC**
>
> **‐ One MCDU**
>
> **‐ One GPS**
>
> **‐ Two IRS**
>
> **‐ One FD in NAV mode**
>
> **> ‐ Two NDs (the temporary display of ND information via the PFD/ND
>   switch is permitted on one side).**

Some helpful information also about **RNP 2** you can find also here: http://www2010.icao.int/NACC/documents/meetings/2013/pbn2013/ops7-en.pdf

Moreover Airbus company under PRO-SPO-51 P 5/10 in FCOM refers as ***RNAV1(2)***
so it takes exactly the same equipment for RNP 1.

Let me know if something is different, or if you have different information from another specific-related documentation.